# Ng-For on a accordion list

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have the following accordion list that uses ng repeat to fill a page with data from a database, at the moment when the page loads the accordions are there and have the data inside but if i click on a random one the first closes, only the first one can open and close.

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" *ngFor="let message of messages">
        <div class="panel panel-default" >
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">data
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                 data
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it's the same id caused this. Try to add `index` for `id`

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" [attr.id]="'accordion_' + i" *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index;">
        <div class="panel panel-default" >
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-parent]="'#accordion_' + i" [attr.href]="'#collapseOne_' + i">{{ message.firstName }} {{ message.lastName }}</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div [attr.id]="'collapseOne_' + i" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  details here {{ message.empId }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/FZZdsh09URKw1GbqseZX/)

Comment: Thanks so much @Lon Yang!